# Why can't I see process with PID 0 using ps?

Tags: unix

I know process `0` is the swapper process in UNIX responsible for process scheduling but why can't I see it using `ps -ef`? How can I see it?

Comment: This is not a programming related question. And the kernel is responsible for process scheduling.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: So which process has PID 0? Is there none?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) says that process 0 is *swapper* or *sched*, and that it's "part of the kernel rather than a normal user-mode process".  Presumably `ps` only shows user-mode processes.  My Ubuntu system has `/proc/1` but no `/proc/0`.

Comment: @Bruce Yes, there is no PID 0. The first process is the init, which has PID 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot see pid 0 because pid 0 does not exist on the system you are using.

Comment: I think this ans need more explanation.

Comment: What more explanation is required? Not all Unix systems have a PID 0 process. The Wikipedia claim that process 0 is the swapper is not true on all Unix systems.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu:

1. The `ps` finds processes by reading the directory `/proc`. The directory /proc doesn't have pid 0. You can check just by `ls /proc`.
2. pid 0 is parent of pid 1 and pid 2

   ```sh
   $ ps -ef
   UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
   root           1       0  0 09:20 ?        00:00:12 /sbin/init auto noprompt
   root           2       0  0 09:20 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
   ```
3. After pid 0 create pid 1 and pid 2. It turns into as the idle process.

   ```c
   static noinline void __init_refok rest_init(void)
   {
       int pid;

       /* spawn pid 1 */
       kernel_thread(kernel_init, NULL, CLONE_FS | CLONE_SIGHAND); 
       /* spawn pid 2 */
       pid = kernel_thread(kthreadd, NULL, CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES); 

       /* Call into cpu_idle with preempt disabled */
       cpu_idle();
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

However kill -0 command usually used to find out if process exists may result true for PID=0

```
[root@example]# kill -0 0 && echo success
success
[root@example]# kill -0 777777 && echo success
bash: kill: (777777) - No such process
```

that's true at least for CentOS 6.4

Comment: From kill(2): *If pid equals 0, then sig is sent to every process in the process group of the calling process.*